# What's the difference between `tsc --build --clean` vs. `rm -rf *.js`?

Tags: typescript, build, tsc, resource-cleanup

I have a quick question on the `tsc` command being used with the arguments `--build --clean`, which I understand is used for cleaning /wiping off the `.js` files generated earlier by the Transpiler (tsc).

What is the speciality or significance of this command? If at all I need to remove all the `.js` files, I can easily accomplish it through `rm -rf *.js` or `del *.js` in the directory.

Can someone educate me on the missing pieces if any?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The difference is that `rm` will happily delete any files, even if they weren't generated by transpiling TypeScript.

> **NOTE!**
>
> `tsc --build --clean` will only delete `.js` files if there is a corresponding `.ts` file that it would have been generated from. This means that, if you rename `.ts` files, delete `.ts` files, or create new `.ts` files, and then run `tsc --build --clean`, old `.js` files that previously had corresponding `.ts` files ***will no longer be deleted***.
>
> If you really want to clean up before a build, especially when the set of `.ts` files has changed, you should instead delete your output folder a different way. For example `rm -rf dist/` in a unix shell, or `rm -r -fo dist/` in Windows PowerShell. Or, assuming you probably use Node.js if you use TypeScript, use a cross-platform package like [`rimraf`](https://npmjs.com/rimraf) to delete your output folder.

Comment: aah.. Thank you. You mean any other random `.js` files in the directory? But I suppose I don't have any arbitrary .js files than the ones which are transpiled by my tsc. Lemme check that out - by having my own .js file for testing purpose and see what `tsc --build --clean` does. But any other significant differences?

Comment: that is a great magic :) i just quickly tested it out.  Any idea how does it differentiate from the .js files it generated and from the rest?

Comment: @itsraghz `tsc` knows what `.ts` files your project has, so it knows what `.js` files it would create when building. Those are the ones `--clean` will then delete.

Comment: Thank you @ruohola. Technically, how does it achieve? does it store a metadata somewhere in order to delete the right .js files - OR only the files corresponds to the .ts files it deletes? Just curious to know the orchestration being used by tsc.

Comment: I just made a quick test. Looks like it deletes the .js files matching with the .ts files. I created a dummy.ts and ran `tsc` to get a dummy.js and then deleted the original `dummy.tsc` before I ran the `tsc --build --clean` just to find out the fact that the `dummy.js` file is left as it is :) so this must be it? Thank you for the good scenario to play around! Are there any other differences - or is that all?

Comment: Yeah, it's completely stateless. If you create `dummy.ts` and `dummy.js`, `--clean` will delete the `.js` file even if it wasn't actually created by building the TypeScript.

Comment: `--clean` is ofc always preferable since it's platform agnostic (`rm` won't likely work on Windows), and it cannot accidentally delete some important files.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you @ruohola, I agree with your words.

Comment: but this only deletes files that would be generated in the outdir folder. Is there a way to make it also delete folders that were previously compiled??

Comment: @haneSmitter I updated the answer. Seems safer to manually delete output folders.

Comment: So is there any point to --clean? Normally I would "clean" specifically to get rid of "left over" files. I'm not worried about the ones that will be overridden by the next --build anyways... I don't want to rmrf the whole directory because that ruins incremental builds.

Answer (score 15):

The difference is `--clean` is useless in general.  If you have ever renamed, moved, or deleted a source file, clean will not clean up the transpiled output.